# Add callback to jquery $.merge function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to add a callback function to jquery `$.merge` function?

I have a js code that merges two arrays into the first one and i need to execute another function as a callback. How can i make this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of why you might need a callback and how you might use a callback with `$.merge`? It isn't clear to me what type of behavior you are trying to produce.

Comment: `$.merge` is synchronous, so just do whatever you want to do after the call...